# Nightwatchjs get sessionID and test assertions failure into after event

Tags: nightwatch.js

In Nightwatchjs there are [event hooks](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-before-each-and-after-each-hooks) which will be triggered before and after test execution.

If during test execution any exception occurs or any assert is failed then, how I can get those failed/errored results into after event for further processing ?

Also in 'after' event sessionID is undefined. However for sessionID one work around is, store sessionID at start of test execution like in 'before' event. Can you please tell me if 'sessionID' is available in 'after' event and how to get it ?

```
module.exports = {

  after : function(browser) {
    browser
      .session(function(session) { console.log("after test suite ID : " + session.sessionId); }); // undefined

    // If assert failure occured, send message.
    // How to get failed assertions/execution errors ?
  },

  'step one' : function (browser) { 
    // Do stuff
  }
};
```